# How to backup current chkconfig configurations

Tags: linux, shell, service

How to backup current chkconfig configurations

```
chkconfig --list
```

list the current services configurations, and when (run level) a service set to start.

I need to backup the chkconfig configurations and restore the same services in another machine with same runlevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output config to file like this `chkconfig -l > /filename`
then on the other system use this script https://gist.github.com/natemccoy/9249545

Comment: Sorry, missed. Edited my answer